# Node and React unable to start server due to elifecycle error code

Tags: node.js, react-native

So this is my first experience with React and I have no idea what this means. Not a lot of helpful information on google about it either. Anybody able to help?

```
josh@josh:~/Documents/node/JuiceBar$ npm start

> JuiceBar@0.1.0 start /home/josh/Documents/node/JuiceBar
> react-native-scripts start

20:13:59: Unable to start server
  See https://git.io/v5vcn for more information, either install watchman or     run the following snippet:
    sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_instances=1024
    sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=12288
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! JuiceBar@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the JuiceBar@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional     logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/josh/.npm/_logs/2018-05-23T00_13_59_395Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately I have yet to figure this out. Really sucks because I am trying to make the front end for a node.js api i coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround (i refuse to call this an answer because i was not able to get it to work without installing another module, unless this module is a dependency for react then technically its an answer). I installed watchman via the command below.

```
sudo npm install watchman --save
```